# Decoding an IP datagram dump manually

Tags: networking, ip, ipv4, datagram

I was practicing questions for this topic and I came across this question:

Look at the 40byte dump of an IP packet containing a TCP segment below (in hexadecimal).

```
45 20 03 c5 78 06 00 00 34 06 ca 1f d1 55 ad 71 c0 a8 01 7e
00 50 9a 03 3e 64 e5 58 df d0 08 b3 80 18 00 de 00 02 00 00
```

Identify all the fields of the IP and TCP header.

Source: Q1 of http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs5480/homeworks/hw3_soln.pdf

Now I do have the datagram format layout of IPv4 in front of me. The thing I don't understand is that in the solution it says that header length is 20bytes but according to the format the bits 4-7 correspond to header length which is 0x03c5 = 965 bytes. However, in the solution 965bytes is the total datagram length.

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

digits != bits.

Assuming zero-based counting, 0x03c5 is hex digits 4-7 in your data.

Bits 4-7 would be the hex 5 appearing earlier.  This header value represents the number of 32-bit words in the header, so you have to multiply by 4 to get 20 as the number of bytes.

Comment: Right...  I'll fix that.

Comment: @Mat - I'll incorporate the final part of your comment now too.  If I knew how to share credit for the answer, I'd be happy to.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at this to dump your headers

https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Data-HexDump-Range/scripts/hdr_examples.pod#IPV4-header

Answer (score 0):

According to the linked PDF document:

```
IP header: IP version 4, Header Length: 20 bytes, ToS = 20, Total Length = 0x03c5 =
965 bytes, ...
```

Seems pretty clear to me - 20 bytes header length, 965 bytes total length
(which matches [Wikipedia on IPv4 headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header#Header) quite nicely).

Comment: That would appear to be the solution that the OP is saying he doesn't understand.  It's nice that you do, but I'm not sure this helps.

Comment: On second thoughts, you're probably right - shame on me.